# Sorting issues on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've got the following that works fine on my local machine (running a MySQL DB) but on Heroku the sort order is wrong, instead of 1,2,3,4,5...11,12,13 etc I get 1,11,12,13,2,3,4,5...!

```
<% @release.releases_tracks.sort { |a,b| a.position <=> b.position }.each do |releases_track| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= releases_track.position %></td>
        <td><%= releases_track.track.name %></td>
        <td><%= releases_track.track.artists.map { |a| a.name}.join (", ") %></td>
        <td><%= releases_track.track.isrc %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

I thought is was because my position column was a varchar, but i've changed to integer, migrated the db on Heroku and it's still doing it! What's going on?

Comment: As a side note, a more concise and probably faster way to sort is `.sort_by { |track| track.position }`, instead of `.sort { |a,b| a.position <=> b.position }`. According to [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by), even Ruby 1.8.6 has `sort_by`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - Your change has fixed this! The sort order is now correct.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the column is still varchar or string. Can you get on the console on Heroku to load an object from the table and inspect the field to make sure if it has indeed changed to integer?

At first, I thought this might have been caused by the difference between mySql and Postgres that Heroku uses, but I do not think that's the case here.

Also, you could use ActiveRecord to handle the sorting...

```
results = YourModel.where('blah...blah..').order('id desc')
```

Comment: Hmmm, managed to pull this via the heroku console: #<ReleasesTrack id: 50, release_id: 112, track_id: 57, position: "12"> Looks like the "12" means it's a string. Question now, is why didn't my migration work!?

Comment: I was previously handling the sorting using ActiveRecord but it was causing me all kinds of other bigger issues when I pushed to Heroku. Very frustrating when everything works as planned locally :(

Comment: Try logging into the console on heroku and do the migrations manually, and watch the output. It might give you some clues, as to whats going wrong. Additionally I like to run it with the tailing `--trace` option, when debugging.

Comment: Are you still having the problem? You can post your migration file here so we could have a clear idea what you are missing or something.  Also, you could install Postgres on your development box, just to safe. Nonetheless, you shouldn't have so much trouble sorting AcitveRecords..

Comment: Try to run your migration by itself. heroku rake db:migrate VERSION=20080906120000